# Symfony 4 how to create multiple forms for an array of entities the most efficient way

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I have a table displaying users, users is an array of User entities which then displays details in a loop in a html table in twig.

For each row i need an editable comments field for each user, i'm not sure what the best way is to create a form for each user to be submitted individually using the form builder.

I'm assuming i would have to loop every single user and create the form and store in the array, but this would be quite inefficient.

Just looking for ideas on what the best approach for this would be.

Comment: sounds like you are looking for a [collection type](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/reference/forms/types/collection.html) but beyond that it is impossible to help you without you providing the code that isn't working.

Comment: It really depends on how you store the "comments". Can you describe how the comments are stored?